# WPF Datagrid: Cancel Sorting event (WPF Bug?)

Tags: wpf, sorting, header

I want to handle all sorting myself, so in the _Sorting event of the Datagrid, I set e.Handled = True. However WPF still fires a collection refresh, and seems to ignore the Handled flag.

When I look at the stack trace, i see this:

```
PresentationFramework.dll!MS.Internal.Data.CollectionViewProxy.Refresh() + 0x2a bytes   
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection.RefreshOverride() + 0x53 bytes 
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.CollectionView.Refresh() + 0x44 bytes 
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.PerformSort(System.Windows.Controls.DataGridColumn sortColumn) + 0xbe bytes  
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DataGridColumnHeader.OnClick() + 0x5d bytes
```

Is this a bug in WPF? Because shouldn't the Handled property prevent these calls from being fired?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you consider to use [`DataGrid.CanUserSortColumns`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.WINDOWS.CONTROLS.DATAGRID.CANUSERSORTCOLUMNS%29;k%28VS.XAMLEDITOR%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2cVERSION%3dV4.0%22%29&rd=true)/[`DataGridColumn.CanUserSort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.WINDOWS.CONTROLS.DATAGRIDCOLUMN.CANUSERSORT%29;k%28VS.XAMLEDITOR%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2cVERSION%3dV4.0%22%29&rd=true) property set to false?

What you want to do may not be linked with `Sorting` event.

Comment: Because if I set CanUserSort to false, the columns become 'unclickable'. They don't receive focus or display sorting arrows, they become static. I want to implement a custom sort for my collection, not disable the sorting UI.